# Geocoding with Latitude and Longitude in OpenLayers3

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, openlayers, geocoding, nominatim

I have Longitude and Latitude, I would like to connect to Geocoding or Nominatim and get the address of these Lat and Lon.

I want to do it in OpenLayers 3 using OSM.

With help from @ThomasG77, I implemented ReverseGeocoding in my code with this function:

```
function simpleReverseGeocoding(lon, lat) {
    fetch('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lon=' + lon + '&lat=' + lat).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.json());
      return response.json();
     }).then(function(json) {

     return json.display_name;
    })
  }
```

But the answer of the JSON is:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

When I show the address in my console:

```
console.log('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lon=' + lon + '&lat=' + lat);
```

The address that it send is Kenia, or "Unable to Geocode"

Obviously, console.log(json.display_name); is undefined.

Do I have to know something about headers or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Nominatim reverse geocoding API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding).

After, it's mainly about knowing HTML and JavaScript.

I've done [a simple demo for reverse geocoding](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/raw/26e61508217ba86a04c19a67cbda0e99/) using OpenLayers. You can look at the code on [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/26e61508217ba86a04c19a67cbda0e99/)

Comment: This example is just that I need. However, it seem that not working. Maybe is my browser or something like that.

Comment: Done some changes to accommodate with IE. It should work now with any recent browsers including IE10+.

Comment: Now it working correctly. Many thanks. Is jast that I need.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. So, I implemented your code. I have to answer my question because is so long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of Lat/Long input, only address.

This [Useful 3rd party libraries](https://openlayers.org/3rd-party/)3

You may be able to find something useful here.

Library Description Maintainer

> The libraries below provide additional functionality by extending OpenLayers or integrating well with it.
>
> - OL-Cesium   Cesium integration library. OpenLayers
>     OL3-LayerSwitcher   Layer control for OpenLayers.   Matt Walker
>     OL3-Popup   Basic popup overlay for OpenLayers. Matt Walker
>     JSTS    JavaScript Topology Suite.  Björn Harrtell
>     OL3-Geocoder    Geocoder Nominatim for OpenLayers.  Jonatas Walker
>     OL3-Photon  Photon geocoder for OpenLayers. Thomas Gratier
>     OL3-ContextMenu Custom Context Menu for OpenLayers. Jonatas Walker
>     OL3-Google-Maps Google Maps integration library.    Mapgears
>     OL3-PanZoom PanZoom and PanZoomBar controls for OpenLayers. Mapgears
>     OL3-Ext Miscellanous classes and functions for OpenLayers.  Jean-Marc Viglino
>     OL3-AnimatedCluster A cluster layer for OpenLayers that animates clusters on
>     zoom change and a select interaction that spread out cluster to allow feature selection in it. Jean-Marc Viglino
>     OL3-Projection-Switcher An OpenLayers Control to switch between projections.    NSIDC
>     Olé Integration of OpenLayers and Esri ArcGIS REST services.    Boundless
>     React OpenLayers    A minimal React wrapper of OpenLayers 3+ written in
>     TypeScript  Allen Kim
>     GWT-OpenLayers 3    A GWT wrapper for OpenLayers 3+ written in Java Tino Desjardins

This option is for address input, [OpenLayers 3 Control Geocoder, ol-geocoder](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder)

> A geocoder extension for OpenLayers 3. Requires OpenLayers v3.11.0 or higher.

[image]

Comment: Ok Thank you. I am using this Library precisely, however, I don´t find the way for look a address by Lat and long.